# Angular - Trying to trigger an Input field upon clicking on a certain element

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an app where I have a certain table with a databse taken from an API, and once I mouse click on any field, an input field should be triggered so that the user will be able to update the value. Here is how it supposed to look:

Initial Stage:

[image: Initial Stage]

after clicking on the First Name field ("gg):

[image]

The problem, as you can see, is once I click on any field in the "First Name" row, input fields are trigerred on every table data field in this row. same with the "Save/Cancel" buttons. I tried fixing it, mainly tried to trigger the function only on a specific item ID but nothing seems to work. I'll appriciate any suggestions!

my code (I put the relevant parts only):

HTML:

```
<table class="table mt-3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Employee ID</th>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Mobile No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Salary</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
      
        <tr *ngFor="let row of employeeData">
            <td>{{row.id}}</td>
            
              <td (click)="onClickOne(row)" *ngIf="!clicked ">{{row.firstName}}
                
                <td *ngIf="clicked">
                <form [formGroup]="formValue">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </form>
              </td>
             

            
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.email}}</td>
            <td>{{row.mobile}}</td>
            <td>{{row.salary}}</td>
            <td>
                <button *ngIf="clicked" type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onClickTwo(row)" (click)="onClickOne(row)"> Save </button>
                <button *ngIf="clicked" class="btn btn-danger mx-3" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button *ngIf="!clicked" (click)="onEdit(row)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                <button *ngIf="!clicked" (click)="deleteEmployee(row)" class="btn btn-danger mx-3">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  
</table>
```

ts: (there is a boolean called "clicked" defined in the component)

```
  onClickOne(row:any) {
  
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/posts").subscribe(res => {
      this.employeeData = res;
      const check = this.employeeData.find((a:any) => {
        console.log(a.id);
        console.log(row.id);
        
        if (a.id === row.id && a.id != a.id+1) {
          console.log(a.id === row.id && a.id != a.id+1);
          this.clicked=!this.clicked;
        }
        
      });

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, because you have the same variable in all your  *ngIf : once its value is modified by a click in a single field, the states of all the other fields will be affected.

You need to have a separate boolean for each row. you can add an optional field to your employData model, for example :

```
clicked?:boolean;
```

and then bind to that :

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of employeeData">
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
        
          <td (click)="onClickOne(row)" *ngIf="!row.clicked ">{{row.firstName}}
            
            <td *ngIf="row.clicked">
            <form [formGroup]="formValue">
              <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </form>
          </td>
```

and change your method as well :

```
onClickOne(row:any) {

this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/posts").subscribe(res => {
  this.employeeData = res;
  const check = this.employeeData.find((a:any) => {
    console.log(a.id);
    console.log(row.id);
    
    if (a.id === row.id && a.id != a.id+1) {
      console.log(a.id === row.id && a.id != a.id+1);
      row.clicked=!row.clicked;
    }
    
  });

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple you only need to add a extra property on your employeeData , like editMode : true / false.

```
<td (click)="row.editMode != row.editMode">{{row.firstName}}></td>
```

If you need a function call just pass the the row object and toggle the editMode for that object.

The rest is just:

```
            <td>
                <button *ngIf="row.editMode" 
                <button *ngIf="!row.editMode" 
                <!-- etc.... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be for the Html

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of employeeData; let i = index">
      <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      
        <td (click)="onClickOne(row,i)" *ngIf="!clicked && index !== i ">{{row.firstName}}
          
          <td *ngIf="index === i">
          <form [formGroup]="formValue">
            <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
          </form>
        </td>
```

this should be for your function in the Ts file

```
clicked: boolean = false;
index: any;

onClickOne(row: any, index: number) {
if(this.clicked && this.index == index) {
  this.index = null;
}else{
  this.index = index;
}
```

}

please use another function name to save

This may help full to you